# mysql select CURDATE +1

Tags: mysql, select

сегодня (30.11.2020) наткнулся на такую проблему. Запрос работал нормально до сегодняшнего дня ошибка была в CURDATE()+1 это потому что если дата 30.11.2020 оно не срабатывает потому что в ноябре нету даты 31. как мне `(GREATEST(0,DATEDIFF(a.end_date, CURDATE()+1)) * b.price) AS OstatokSuma` это исправить подскажите пожалуйста

```
SELECT
a.`id` AS PacketID,
b.`name` AS NamePacket,
DATE_FORMAT(a.`AddDate`,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS ADDDATE,
DATE_FORMAT(a.`start_date`,'%d-%m-%Y') AS start_date,
DATE_FORMAT(a.`end_date`,'%d-%m-%Y') AS end_date,
c.`login`,
a.user_id,
GREATEST(0,DATEDIFF(a.`end_date`, CURDATE())) AS OstatokDate, b.price, c.discount,
(GREATEST(0,DATEDIFF(a.`end_date`, CURDATE()+1)) * b.price) AS OstatokSuma
FROM
users_packet_groups AS a
LEFT JOIN packet_groups AS b
  ON a.`group_id` = b.`id`
LEFT JOIN users AS c
  ON a.`user_id`=c.`id`
WHERE user_id = 7549
```

Comment: `CURDATE()+1` - это вообще бред с точки зрения MySQL. Правильно - `CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Comment: Akina, спасибо большое за подсказку